# How to do zoom to google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to get map with zoom but I don't get it. when the Activity map is open I get this:

[image]

and I need to get this:
[enter image description here][2]

This is my code:

```
 mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( -1.0f), 1, null);
```

so which zoom I need to use to get it, like the Image?

thanks for help :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Implementing this-:

```
CameraUpdate center=
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(40.76793169992044,
                                                 -73.98180484771729));
    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

    map.moveCamera(center);
    map.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To zoom particular location in map**

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code To zoom on Map with particular Lat Long.

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currLat, currLong), 14.0f));
```